# Entities passed to the choice field must be managed - different on app.php and on app_dev.php

Tags: forms, symfony

Welcome!

I've added a field to a form

```
    ->add('languageLevel', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER => Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER,
            Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE => Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE,
            Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED => Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED,
            Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT => Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT
        ]
    ])
```

This form saves entity 'Meme' with the same property

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="language_level", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $languageLevel;
```

The prod.log gives me this:

```
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] request.INFO: Matched route "meme_add". {"route":"meme_add","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\MemeController::addAction","_route":"meme_add"},"request_uri":"http://keenweasel.com/meme/add","method":"GET"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"acid","provider":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\UserProvider"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] php.WARNING: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given at /var/www/keen/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1239)"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] php.WARNING: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given at /var/www/keen/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1592)"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\RuntimeException: "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?" at /var/www/keen/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php line 98 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager? at /var/www/keen/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php:98)"} []
[2017-12-17 23:41:18] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
```

in dev.log on my dev machine there is nothing like that, and it works fine. On prod I get error 500. Any help please? I tried removing vendor and installing it one more time on both dev and prod servers. Clearing cache multiple time with --env=prod.

---

### EDIT

Ok, got the same problem on dev server (just switched from app_dev.php to app.php in apache config and added app/autoload.php)

```
/**
 * @Route("/meme/add", name="meme_add")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @internal param Request $request
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!$user || !$user->hasRole('ROLE_MEME_ADD_AWAITING')) {
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'You need to login');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
    }

    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }

    $meme = new Meme();
    $form = $this->createForm(MemeAddType::class, $meme);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_MEME_ADD_AWAITING')) {
            $meme->setPublishingStatus('awaiting-publishing');
        } else if ($this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_MEME_ADD_MAIN')) {
            $meme->setPublishingStatus('published');
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($meme);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render(
        '@App/memes/add.html.twig',
        [
            'memeAddForm' => $form->createView()
        ]
    );
}
```

The form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Language;
use AppBundle\Entity\Meme;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class MemeAddType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('textOne', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'A phrase or a word',
                'attr' => ['style' => 'width:320px; height: 110px']
            ])
            ->add('textOneLang', EntityType::class , [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'language',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Language of the phrase of the word',
                'data' => 2

            ])
            ->add('textTwo', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Translation, might be with an example',
                'attr' => ['style' => 'width:320px; height: 110px']
            ])
            ->add('textTwoLang', EntityType::class , [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'language',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Language of the translation of the phrase of the word',
                'data' => 2
            ])
            ->add('languageLevel', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER => Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER,
                    Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE => Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE,
                    Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED => Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED,
                    Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT => Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT
                ]
            ])
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class)
            ->add(
                'save',
                SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'save']
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Meme::class
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_meme_add';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_bundle_meme_add';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do `Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER, Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE, Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED, Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT` refer to ?

Comment: These are just strings.

Comment: languageLevel is mapped, what does the object passed to the form contains ?

Comment: I've updated the question with form and controller. Also, replicated the same problem on dev server. Weird, that there was no problem on app_dev.php for some reason both on dev and prod servers.

Comment: If you have the same problem on dev, can you post a more verbose debug ? The error you post doesn't wire back to any of your files, which seem ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what was going on was that I had

```
 'data' => 2
```

in the textOneLang  form element, so it was failing when it was given to  spl_object_hash() function which only accepts objects, not integers. Data transformer was not used for that. But this 'data' parameter wasn't supposed to be there in the first place, don't know how it ended up there. Probably, when trying to debug it. Lesson learned, have all the options figured out and also, just dump what you have as parameter in spl_object_hash().

The difference between app_dev.php and app.php didn't have anything to do with it. It was probably cached somehow in app_dev.php and worked on some older version.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your formType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Language;
use AppBundle\Entity\Meme;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class MemeAddType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('textOne', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'A phrase or a word',
                'attr' => ['style' => 'width:320px; height: 110px']
            ])
            ->add('textOneLang', EntityType::class , [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'language',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Language of the phrase of the word',
                'data' => 2

            ])
            ->add('textTwo', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Translation, might be with an example',
                'attr' => ['style' => 'width:320px; height: 110px']
            ])
            ->add('textTwoLang', EntityType::class , [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'language',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => 'Language of the translation of the phrase of the word',
                'data' => 2
            ])
            ->add('languageLevel', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER => Meme::LEVEL_BEGINNER,
                    Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE => Meme::LEVEL_INTERMEDIATE,
                    Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED => Meme::LEVEL_ADVANCED,
                    Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT => Meme::LEVEL_EXPERT
                ]
            ])
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class)
            ->add(
                'save',
                SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'save']
                ]
            )
        ;
        $builder->get('languageLevel')->resetViewTransformers();
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Meme::class
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_meme_add';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfection!         

$builder->get('languageLevel')->resetViewTransformers();

is the magic. Could you explain why is that necessary in this case, it would be great educational value! :)

Comment: Please check this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html . I hope it  will help you to get knowledge about transfomers.